# PowerShell Import DnsShell Module

Tags: powershell

So here's the list of available modules in this directory. As you can see `DnsShell` is there.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

Directory: C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

```
ModuleType Name                                ExportedCommands                                                             
---------- ----                                ----------------                                                             
Manifest   ActiveDirectory                     {Get-ADRootDSE, New-ADObject, Rename-       ADObject, Move-ADObject...}             
Manifest   AppLocker                           {Set-AppLockerPolicy, Get-AppLockerPolicy, Test-AppLockerPolicy, Get-AppLo...
Manifest   BitsTransfer                        {Add-BitsFile, Remove-BitsTransfer, Complete-BitsTransfer, Get-BitsTransfe...
Manifest   CimCmdlets                          {Get-CimAssociatedInstance, Get-CimClass, Get-CimInstance, Get-CimSession...}
Binary     DnsShell                                                                                                         
Script     ISE                                 {New-IseSnippet, Import-IseSnippet, Get-    IseSnippet}                           
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics    {Get-WinEvent, Get-Counter, Import-Counter, Export-Counter...}               
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Host           {Start-Transcript, Stop-Transcript}                                          
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-  ItemProperty, Join-Path...}               
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {Get-Acl, Set-Acl, Get-PfxCertificate, Get-Credential...}                    
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-Table, Format-Wide...}                   
Manifest   Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Disable-WSManCredSSP, Enable- WSManCredSSP,   Get-WSManCredSSP, Set-WSManQui...
Script     PSDiagnostics                       {Disable-PSTrace, Disable-   PSWSManCombinedTrace, Disable-WSManTrace, Enable...
Binary     PSScheduledJob                      {New-JobTrigger, Add-JobTrigger, Remove-JobTrigger, Get-JobTrigger...}       
Manifest   PSWorkflow                          {New-PSWorkflowExecutionOption, New-PSWorkflowSession, nwsn}                 
Manifest   PSWorkflowUtility                   Invoke-AsWorkflow                                                            
Manifest   TroubleshootingPack                 {Get-TroubleshootingPack, Invoke-TroubleshootingPack}
```

When I run the command to `Import-Module DnsShell`, I get this error and I dont know why..

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Import-Module DnsShell
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 
'file:///C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsShell\DnsShell.dll' or    one of its dependencies. Operation is 
not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module DnsShell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileLoadException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

**Note:** I would have posted pictures but I needed a rep of at least 10 in serverfault

Comment: Did you extract the whole DnsShell package to the Modules folder, or just the .dll?

Comment: @squillman All of it.

Comment: Did you try to delete it and recopy?  Maybe the extract got corrupted.

Comment: @squillman Yes, still no luck. Everything is there.

Comment: Ok.  Maybe it's blocked.  Look at the file properties on DnsShell.dll and see if, on the general tab, you see an Unblock button at the bottom.

Comment: @squillman That was it. It was blocked because I downloaded it on my company's computer. Thank you. Post this as an answer and I'll give you credit! Thanks again!

Comment: Done!  Glad you got it going!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the file properties on DnsShell.dll and see if, on the general tab, you see an Unblock button at the bottom.  This can happen if you download the files from a remote source.

Comment: Files extracted from a .ZIP containing an Alternate Data Streams will all contain the additional streams as well.

Comment: In addition to this, I was also getting a `DnsShell.Format.ps1xml : File skipped because of the following validation exception: DnsShell.Format.ps1.xml cannot be loaded`, which was solved by doing the above (unblocking) the DnsShell.Format.ps1xml file

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the version of PowerShell you are running.  This module runs with 2.0 ONLY. If you are getting the error run 2.0 by running "powershell.exe -version 2.0" Then import the module.

Answer (score 0):

Download module from: http://dnsshell.codeplex.com/

1- Extract DnsShell.zip to one of the paths shown by $Env:PSModulePath

2- Run: Import-Module DnsShell

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question is rather pointedly regarding an error with that exact procedure. If you have information on how to overcome the problem, please add it to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me only works doing this:

- extract to another folder;
- unblock all files;
- copy the dnsshell folder to modules folder;
- import the module;

Answer (score 0):

If unblocking with the Explorer doesn't work or if you have many files to unblock, you can remove alternate data streams with the `streams.exe` Windows Sysinternals tool located at https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/streams.aspx.

```
streams -s -d DNSSHELL_DIRECTORY
```

This command **will remove every alternate data stream** in the `DNSSHELL_DIRECTORY` files and all of its subdirectories. So don't use it on random parts of the filesystem.

To be sure, you can first list the streams with:

```
streams -s DNSSHELL_DIRECTORY
```